# How can I write the next logical expression in Inno Setup properly?

Tags: inno-setup, directive, preprocessor

Here's the pseudocode for what I need to write using the preprocessor directives:

```
(IF VAR == NOT DEFINED) OR (VAR == DEFINED AND VAR == 0) THEN
{a few lines of code}
```

How can I write that logical expression in one line?

I tried this:

```
#if (defined(VAR) == 0) || ((defined(VAR) == 1) && (VAR == "0"))
```

but it didn't work. It says:

> Undeclared identifier: "VAR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems reasonable. I would have expected it to work too.

Anyway, your code gives an impression that "0" should be a default value of the `VAR`. So this should do:

```
#ifndef VAR
#define VAR "0"
#endif

#if VAR == "0"
{a few lines of code}
#endif
```

Comment: What will be the default value if I just write `#define VAR` without actually giving it a value?

Comment: Formally, it won't have a value and you should not use such variable in expressions.